# How to test the REST endpoint that is given like this?

Tags: rest, authentication, soapui, apex

Example:
**curl https://api.signable.co.uk/v1/users/1000
-u d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e:x**

(refer: https://developer.signable.co.uk/v1/user/)

How to test the endpoint using SoapUI 5.6.0? Or If someone can share how to test it in Apex/Salesforce, that would be helpful.

Comment: Is your question *"How to use ussername and password in SoapUI?"*

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to establish a connection for this.

Comment: Or even if you could tell me how to test this endpoint in web browser with return values in JSON, that would be helpful. I am not quite getting the format. I saw definitions like https:// hostname / api ? apikey=value but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Here is the actual test key 3cffb552d1725d89928702a5624ff601 Please see if you get a response.